# Run individual cpp file each have main()

Tags: c++, eclipse

I want to run many individual cpp programs in eclipse.

Each one is a short complete program and each contains its own main function. Also i want to share some common libraries with all these programs. Do you have any idea about that ?

Here is the problem when i try to run 2 individual codes

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "Displayimage"  ./draw_rectangle.o ./showImg.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui
./showImg.o: In function `main':
showImg.cpp:(.text.startup+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
./draw_rectangle.o:draw_rectangle.cpp:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Displayimage] Error 1
```

Comment: Learn how to use CMake.

Comment: So, build them as separate executables?

Comment: Any references  @Quantum Pyysicst

Comment: not really clear what is the problem. Of course eclipse allows you to create more than a single executable

Comment: Please take a look now

Comment: You can't have a `main()` in `draw_rectangle.cpp` and `showImg.cpp` if you are going to link the .o files for these in the same executable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in Eclipse might actually not be how to *run* them, but how to *build* (compile and link) them.

You can easily run any program from Eclipse via it's "Run" menu. On the other side, if you want to build them, you might need to create a separate Eclipse project for each of them (if managed builds are used).

However for makefile/CMake projects, multiple executables can be part of a single project as well.

For the common libraries, you can create them as separate projects too and let the executable projects depend on them. With CMake there are other options as well (could be part of a single project easily, or find_package scripts can be created, etc.)

Comment: Please take a look now

Comment: As said, you cannot link them both together into a single executable (there must be only one `main()` in each executable), so you need to create a separate executable for each .cpp with `main()`. And then you can run each of them separately. I.e. the easiest might be to create separate project for each.

Comment: created but still same problem